# Using MobX in ReactJS and ReactNative hybrid app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

Me and my team are building a ReactJS and ReactNative hybrid app. The idea is to share code as much as possible. 
MobX is a nice solution for state management but we stumbled on a problem.
Our shared state stores must be used by the ReactJS app and the React Native app. The same is valid for our shared Higher Order Components who are supposed to observe state changes of the state stores.

So, in order to register class as MobX observer, in RN we need to

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react/native'
```

and for ReactJS we need to

```
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
```

React Native is complaining about the ReactJS import and vice versa.

Can somebody help me to figure out a solution for this and make the state store usable for the both platforms?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the error you getting!

Comment: Sounds like something that can be easily solved in your build, like a webpack alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `import {observer} from 'mobx-react'` in React Native in mobx-react from *4.1.4* version.
https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/pull/222

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!